# Issue with 'upper-case' module in Node.js: ERR_REQUIRE_ESM when using require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, uppercase

I am facing a problem with the 'upper-case' module in my Node.js application. I'm trying to use the upper-case module to convert a string to uppercase, but I'm encountering an error related to ESM and require().

Node.js Version:

Node.js v20.9.0

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var uc = require('upper-case');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write(uc.upperCase("hello world!"));
    res.end();
}).listen(5000);

console.log('Uppercase Server running...');
```

Error Message:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ... not supported.
Instead, change the require of index.js to a dynamic import().
```

I have tried using different syntax for require, but the issue persists.
I have checked the 'upper-case' module's documentation and GitHub page for any known issues, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: why do you want to use a deprecated library?

Comment: instead of requiring the deprecated library ... `const uc = str => str.toUpperCase();` then the rest of your code remains unchanged

Comment: or, switch to `ESModules` - but that would require changing all your `require`s to `imports` of course - and all your `module.exports` to `export` - in my opinion, if your codebase is small, do it ... ESmodules can easily import commonjs ones

Answer (score -1):

As per the error state itself it no longer uses require.

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ... not supported.
> Instead, change the require of index.js to a dynamic import().

If you really need you should try to import insted, Try something like below :

```
import { upperCase } from "upper-case";
```

or else use javascript inbuilt functionality instead:

```js
var str = "uppercase";
var res = str.toUpperCase();
console.log(res)
```

Comment: you can't `import` and `require` in the same file ... clearly OP isn't using ESModules